# Using select query for between where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to find out a date falls between two other dates which are selected from a different table in Microsoft SQL Server

I.e. I want to do something like

```
     Select A.* from  ( select member.key, 
           case when effective_date between (select month_start and month_end 
           from sales_month 
           where month=2 and year=2013) bucket_1
           then 1 else 0 from member ) as A
          where a.bucket_1 != 0
```

I have to duplicate case statement for different months. Any ideas / help?

Thanks

Shankar.

Comment: Why doesn't that work?

Comment: BETWEEN expects two arguments...I'm assuming that's why

Comment: Refer to the documentation on the use of the BETWEEN statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: You can only return 1 value from a subquery, and `AND` where it is makes no sense in the query.

Comment: Syntax error and I think in SQL server it is a boolean operator. Hence will not work. I understand the between clause, but would like to achieve something like I posted in the query.

Comment: I believe you can use the same query but you have to separate the selecte statements for date. Between (select first date ) and (select second date)

Comment: If you really wanted to go the sub query route, you would need to do something like WHERE effective_date BETWEEN (SELECT month_start FROM sales_month WHERE year = 2013 AND month = 2) AND (SELECT month_start FROM sales_month WHERE year = 2013 AND month = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use variables to hold the information.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = month_start
       , @EndDate = month_end
FROM sales_month
WHERE [month] = 2 AND [year] = 2013

SELECT *
from member
where effective_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Answer (score 5):

This could be done with a JOIN:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM member m
JOIN sales_month sm
    ON sm.month = 2
    AND sm.year = 2013
    AND m.effective_date BETWEEN sm.month_start AND sm.month_end;
```

Comment: Thanks. But my query which I am using inside another will not allow - hence I would need to use like the one I have stated above. To be more clear I have a query in which I am using a case statement. For the case statement I have to use the date condition.

Comment: ` case effective_date between 
           (select month_start and month_end 
           from sales_month 
           where month=2 and year=2013)`

Comment: @Shankar what does "will not allow" mean?

Comment: As I said, I am using it inside a SELECT CASE statement. So I will not be able to join inside the case. I would need to define like the example I have provided above within the CASE statement

Comment: @Shankar - Would you be so kind as to edit your question to show the larger issue you are trying to address?  A `join` within a `case` is within the realm of possibility.

Comment: Finally ended up using variables and do the same.

Comment: @Shankar - Still not seeing why a `join` could not be used.  I am starting to wonder if what you are really trying to do is to produce rows with a `member.key` and a `bucket` column for each month in a year indicating whether they had any sales in that month.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates that you expect, you can use a join:

```
select m.*
from member m join
     sales_month sm
     on m.effective_date between sm.month_start and sm.month_end and
        sm.month = 2 and sm.year = 2013
```

Otherwise, try a correlated subquery with `exists`:

```
select m.*
from member m
where exists (select 1 from sales_month where month=2 and year=2013 and m.effective_date between month_start and month_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to get the month and year from a table. You're looking for all members whose effective date falls in February of 2013, right? What is `sales_month` doing for you here?

```
DECLARE @m INT, @y INT;
SELECT @m = 2, @y = 2013;


DECLARE @d DATETIME;
SET @d = DATEADD(MONTH, @m-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @y-1900, 0));

SELECT m.*            -- don't use SELECT *!
 FROM dbo.member AS m -- always use schema prefix!
  WHERE effective_date >= @d 
  AND effective_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @d); -- don't use BETWEEN!
```

If it needs to come from a table (e.g. your sales month is not the same as a calendar month for some reason), then use a join, but I'm not sure what your `BETWEEN` logic really means. I'll leave it in in case it's logical, but in most cases it's not.

```
SELECT m.*
 FROM dbo.member AS m
 INNER JOIN dbo.sales_month AS s
 ON m.effective_date BETWEEN s.month_start AND s.month_end
 WHERE s.[month] = 2 AND s.[year] = 2013; -- don't use reserved words as column names!
```

Relevant links:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Time periods in business are often peculiar.  A _sales month_ may be constructed so that is it always composed of either 4 or 5 full weeks.  In that case a lookup table might be just the ticket to determine the start and end dates.

Comment: @HABO maybe, but I've also seen a table incorrectly used this way. Not that it hurts either way, but it'd be good to get clarification from the OP whether the table is necessary.